# Use sql-maven-plugin inside my own plugin implementation

Tags: java, sql, maven, plugins, mojo

I'm developing in Java a maven plugin which needs to run different SQL scripts, among other things. I don't know how to run existing SQL Scripts from Java so I started to wonder if I can use the `sql-maven-plugin` inside my own plugin implementation for executing SQL scripts. I found nothing close to this while googling so I guess it's not realistic, but want to be sure.

EDIT: I tried to use the `mojo-executor`, however I don't know how to add my executions to the structure proposed by the mojo executor.

Comment: The linked question provides a more general way of executing a Maven plugin from another plugin (through the Mojo Executor, which in version 1.5.2 supports Maven 3)

Comment: Thank you so much, however I still dont know how to handle the executions